# Http post data missing or tampered in php from as3 client

Tags: php, actionscript-3, http, post

We are running into a strange problem. We have a as3 and php based facebook application which has half a million MAU. For quite a no of times in a day the data we send from as3 client to php server, either they are lost completely/partially or the text data is replaced by some strange characters (eg "!@#$%"). This happens for 2%/3% of total requests (average 5 millions requests in a day) every day.

Also from application log we can see the response body is getting chopped for large data sent from server to client. It happens for 5% response in average in a day. Is it due to packet loss in network or its a bug of web server or flash client?

We are unable to find out which is causing the problem. Is there any thing specific we need to do for http request/response reliability. Or just it happens in all web apps having large no of user visits every day and we need to tolerate this for ever? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some examples of how the data is getting mangled? What it should have been when it left AS and what it was when it arrived at PHP?

Comment: 1. Post body from AS3:{"params":"state=completed|count=0|name=Give 'em  Hell!","action":"saveUserAchievement"} and in PHP it has been received as {"params":"state=completed|count=0|name=Give 'em  @#!*% !","action":"saveUserAchievement"}. 2. Post body from AS3 client:params=count=1|productName=Scout|col=10|row=24|item_identifier=Barracks&action=saveStartFactoryProduction&header=userId=60,time=03:27:20 PM,protocolVersion=1_0_70  where in server it's received as header=userId=60,time=03:27:20 PM,protocolVersion=1_0_70. 3.Similarly from server we send a long json string but in clnt we recv a part.

Comment: In the first one, the word `Hell` appears to have been censored. I have no idea *why* this would be, that that is what appears to have happened. The second one I would say that it has been treated as `application/x-form-www-urlencoded`, so that you would end up (in PHP) with `$_POST['params']`, `$_POST['action']`, and `$_POST['header']` being set. Would you say that my summary is correct? Also, if so, what *should* be happening?

Comment: Actually all the posts are url encoded as we are using URLRequest from as3 lib and setting the data in urlRequest.data.If this is encoded how the word "hell" can be censored?Second one also encoded as "application/x-form-www-urlencoded" and we write entire data as json string against a key named batchRequest="".We take the value out in server side and json decode,split the response by using the delimiters.Any explanation why some part of the string is being missed.Why these are not happening in all the cases?Same kind of requests just work in most of the cases and fails for few cases.Why few?

Comment: AS3 bug? Sounds like what your doing should work... I'm out of ides I'm afraid. Regarding censorship - this is usually a client-side setting (although I'm not aware of such a setting in AS3, and it seems like an odd thing to do anyway - but that is certainly what it looks like). Is the problem limited to a select set of clients, or happening randomly to all clients?

Comment: Really thanks for your attention.I tested 2 cases.Both are Firefox user. Flash player versions are 10.0.12 and 11.0.1.I am sure the problem happens randomly in all the clients.Both the users are old users and have been playing our game for long time. They must not have problems earlier.Also we get a long json response back(not encoded) from server for a particular request. 4-5% cases of total we get mangled response.Same as the request issue we are discussing. So we are losing data in both request and response for our users.If it's only as3 bug, then why the issue is observed in response also.

Comment: This never happens in our test server. It happens only in production server.

Comment: Will increase traffic, but you could try base64 encoding the messages in transition, in case they are getting mangled by the network (*might* also help with censorship)

Comment: We have enabled gzip encoding in the nginx getway of pour production server.But it never helped. Do you still think base64 would help?

Comment: Probably not, sounds like the data is probably getting mangled before it leaves AS3. Have you looked at the raw POST body, to confirm whether the messages are arriving mangled, or being interpreted wrong? I would say it can only be one or the other...

Comment: You can access it using [`php://input`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) - something like `$in = fopen('php://input','r'); $out = fopen('rawbody.txt','w'); stream_copy_to_stream($in,$out);`. Or you could use something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: Also, if you use something like Charles to monitor network traffic on your machine, you can see the outgoing POST request in raw form, inspect its response, as well as manually edit & resend requests.

Comment: Are you using Query String or post method to post data from as3 to php?